# IBM Watson visualRecognition.classify method times out

Tags: android, ibm-watson

I'm using IBM Watson to classify images from an Android device.

I have set a Visual Recognition service. I tested posting the image file from the command line with `curl`.

Everything works fine but when I use the java code that I've found in the documentation, the request times out.

Below is a snippet of my code;

```
private fun classifyImage(imagePath: String): ClassifiedImages {
    val file = File(imagePath)
    val visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(VERSION, API_KEY)
    val imagesStream = FileInputStream(imagePath)
    val classifyOptions = ClassifyOptions.Builder()
        .imagesFile(imagesStream)
        .imagesFilename(file.name)
        .threshold(0.1f)
        .addClassifierId(CLASSIFIER_ID).build()
    val classifiedImages = visualRecognition.classify(classifyOptions).execute()
    Log.d("classifyImage", classifiedImages.customClasses.toString())

    return classifiedImages
}
```

I should add that I'm not doing what the documentation suggests: I should be accessing a web service from the phone and Watson from the web service. This is just an experiment. I still don't understand why if I access the service from my PC with `curl` it works but if I do it from the Android client it does not

Comment: I managed to get it working using OkHttpClient and making a simple POST. It would be good to know why using the Watson SDK did not work